# cordova run ios is interrupted due to the plugin ADAL

Tags: cordova, ios-simulator, adal

I am getting following error while execute command 'cordova run ios'

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
> Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
> Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
> Library not loaded: @rpath/ADAL.framework/ADAL
> Referenced from:  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBD2-4120-B94A-BCB9DA95F774/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DBBC-4ECC-AF4D-7B087584A6A9/СГК.app/СГК
> Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/ADAL.framework/ADAL' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/ADAL.framework/ADAL' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CBD2-4120-B94A-BCB9DA95F774/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DBBC-4ECC-AF4D-7B087584A6A9/СГК.app/Frameworks/ADAL.framework/ADAL' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'armv7,armv7s,arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Develop
> (terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

When I start this app from xcode it works fine, but I need to start it from command line.

Xcode run my app when emulator type=Rosetta. I tried to build the application via xcodebuild with x86_64 architecture, but it doesn't help.

Comment: did you got any solution for this because same also happens to me! it is not building bcz of this x86_64 architecture. showing like you can only run by having arm64 architecture.

Comment: No, I didn't got a solution.

Comment: is it bcz of adal plugin? bcz mine shows like this is being only in arm64 architecture and my Mac simulators are all of x86_64 architecture.